# revert,assert,require,throw what is the difference？

Tags: solidity, ether

Who can tell me what is the difference between revert,assert,require,throw!

Comment: It's always better to mention your findings when you ask a question which might lead to get an answer on where you need the exact clarification. This question shows no effort at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw is the old mechanism for reverting the state of the current call (and all its sub-calls)

> From version 0.4.13 the throw keyword is deprecated and will be phased out in the future.

Revert is the new, preferred mechanism for reverting a call

> The revert function can be used to flag an error and revert the current call.

As for assert and require:

> The convenience functions assert and require can be used to check for conditions

The difference between them being

Assert:

> The assert function should only be used to test for internal errors and to check invariants

Require:

> The require function should be used to ensure valid conditions, such as inputs, or contract state variables are met, or to validate return values from calls to external contracts

e.g.

```
contract Sharer {
    function sendHalf(address addr) payable returns (uint balance) {
        require(msg.value % 2 == 0); // Only allow even numbers
        uint balanceBeforeTransfer = this.balance;
        addr.transfer(msg.value / 2);
        // Since transfer throws an exception on failure and
        // cannot call back here, there should be no way for us to
        // still have half of the money.
        assert(this.balance == balanceBeforeTransfer - msg.value / 2);
        return this.balance;
    }
}
```

[Source: Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=throw#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)